# how to resume the timer from where it was paused using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My Problem is when i press PAUSE btn & after few seconds  again if i press the play button   then then timer is starting from the beginning .` **The timer should continue from the current pause time,if user clicks play button followed by pause button.**

Please  help me for this, i am trying to solve this issue since last 2 days. But still its not solved as per my app requirement.

```
function myApp() { 
  this.paused = false;
  this.paused = true // set pause to true (stop)
  this.isactive = false; // countdown is active
  return this.observer(); // call and return the "observer" method of the "myApp" class
}

myApp.prototype.observer = function() { // observer method
  var self = this; // set this to self (this is the current instance of this class)

  $('#btn_start').on('click', function(event){ // where an user click on "btn_start"
    event.preventDefault();
    self.play('mp3'); // call the play method and store the state in a public var
    self.countdown(30, self.onEnd); // 30 is the audio duration - second parameter is the callback when the audio is finished
    self.isactive = true;
  });
  return this; // return this instance
};

myApp.prototype.play = function() { // play method
  var song = document.getElementById('audiosource');
  if (this.paused === true)
  {
    console.log('play song');
    song.play();
    this.paused = false;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('pause song');
    song.pause();
    this.paused = true;
  }
  return this;
};

myApp.prototype.countdown = function(duration, callback) { // countdown method
  var self = this, // class instance
       countdown = null, // countdown
       ctx = null; // setIntervall clearer
       timer = duration; // timer

  if (this.isactive === true) // if this method yet called
  {
    return false;
  }
  countdown = function() {
      console.log('start countdown:' + self.paused);
    if (timer === 0)
    {
       clearInterval(ctx);
       callback.call(this);
       return false;
    }
    if (self.paused === false) // if not in pause
    {
      timer -= 1;
      console.log(timer);
      $('#timer > span').html(timer);
    }
  };
  ctx = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
};

myApp.prototype.onEnd = function() {
  // when the audio is finish..
 alert ('end of the song');
};

 ;   $(function() {
  new myApp();
});
```

Comment: you didn't include any code in your question.

Comment: @KevinB I have updated my question with jquery code. And also i have included the complete code in my Fiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/XYevE/1/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FUsing_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Sorry, i'm not going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure your app differently

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="timer">click play</div>
    <a href="#" id="btn_start">PLAY</a>
</div>

<audio id="audiosource">
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/en/get_ready.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/button-1.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>


<audio  id="a_1" >
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/en/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/en/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio  id="a_2" >
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/2.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio   id="a_3" >
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/3.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/3.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio id="a_4" >
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/4.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/4.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio  id="a_5" >
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/audio/en/5.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.virtuagym.com/audio/en/5.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    // function to play sounds, calls `done` when sounds are finished to play
    // here you should adjust timings for your audio
    var playGetReady = function (done) {
        var ids = ['audiosource', 'a_5', 'a_4', 'a_3', 'a_2', 'a_1'],
            playNext = function () {
                var id = ids.shift();
                document.getElementById(id).play();
                if (ids.length) {
                    setTimeout(playNext, 1000);
                } else {
                    done();
                }
            };
        playNext();
    };

    // constructor
    function App($el, startFrom) {
        this.$el = $el; // root element
        this.$timer = this.$('#timer'); // find element to render countdown to
        this.$button = this.$('#btn_start'); // play/pause button
        // $.proxy(fn, ctx); makes `ctx` to be referenced by `this` inside `fn`
        // sets handler on button
        this.$button.click($.proxy(this.buttonHandler, this));
        // sets value to start countdown
        this.set(startFrom);
        // we're not running yet
        this.intervalHandle = null;
    };

    // look for elements inside of root element
    App.prototype.$ = function () {
        return this.$el.find.apply(this.$el, arguments);
    };

    // called on play/pause button click
    App.prototype.buttonHandler = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor default action
        this.toggle(); // toggle play/pause
    };

    App.prototype.start = function () {
        var self = this;
        playGetReady(function () { // play get ready sound
            // start countdown
            self.intervalHandle = setInterval($.proxy(self.tick, self), 1000);
            // change button text to PAUSE
            self.$button.text('PAUSE');
        });
    };

    App.prototype.stop = function () {
        // stop countdown
        clearInterval(this.intervalHandle);
        // set `intervalHandle` to null to be able to check whether
        // countdown is running or not
        this.intervalHandle = null;
        // change button text to PLAY
        this.$button.text('PLAY');
    };

    App.prototype.toggle = function () {
        // if running
        if (this.intervalHandle) {
            // then stop
            this.stop();
        // if not
        } else {
            // then start
            this.start();
        }
    };

    // sets new value for countdown
    App.prototype.set = function (timeLeft) {
        this.counter = timeLeft;
    };

    // called every second to update counter, rerender, call `end` callback
    // and play sound
    App.prototype.tick = function () {
        // update countdown
        this.counter -= 1;
        // push new countdown to page
        this.render();
        if (this.counter === 0) { // if countdown is finished
            this.stop(); // stop decreasing it
            this.end(); // end callback, ask for new value or terminate
        }
    };

    // pushed countdown to page
    App.prototype.render = function () {
        this.$timer.text(this.counter);
    };

    // on end callback
    App.prototype.end = function () {
        // ask for new countdown
        var text = prompt('end of the first exercise, NOw lets play the second exercise for your with another by loading its time');
        if (text) { // if user entered any
            var next = Number(text); // convert it to number
            this.set(next); // set new countdown value
            this.render(); // push changes to page
            this.start(); // start countdown
        } else { // if user entered nothing
            // do nothing
            this.$timer.text('You\'re done'); // tell user he finished
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        var app = new App($('#app'), 5); // create app
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note, you should adjust timings in `playGetReady` according to your sounds. Also, only `a_5` and `a_1` are loading.

Hope it'll help. I'd also recommend you reading tutorial or book on JavaScript.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/5/)

Comment: can you please provide me an logic to implement `Mute/unmute` functionality to your fiddle code? Here i tried http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/25/ but its not working..

Comment: I can see you set `this.muted`, but you don't use it to prevent playing sound. You should check if it's muted like with `this.newTimer` in `start` method.

Comment: its difficult man. i kept but its not mute sound is not happening  on click of link `toggle volume`

Comment: @rani Oh, I see. You need to either move muting out of `App` or bring functionality of `playGetReady` inside `App`. Observer design pattern can help keep `playGetReady` and `App separate. The pattern is very common in js code, it is also very common to implement it as custom events. I like `Backbone.Event` for this. This is not trivial, you'll have to do some research and learn new techniques. I'll be glad to help you. But I don't have much time. Leave you questions [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38274/discussion-between-zaquest-and-user2732367). I'll answer as fast as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You must store the timeleft somewhere and when you press play again, you resume from timeleft.
I just added the timeleft var.

```
function myApp() { 

this.timeleft = 30;

  this.paused = false;
  this.paused = true; // set pause to true (stop)
  this.isactive = false; // countdown is active
  return this.observer(); // call and return the "observer" method of the "myApp" class
}

myApp.prototype.observer = function() { // observer method
  var self = this; // set this to self (this is the current instance of this class)

  $('#btn_start').on('click', function(event){ // where an user click on "btn_start"
    event.preventDefault();
    self.play('mp3'); // call the play method and store the state in a public var
    self.countdown( self.timeleft, self.onEnd); // 30 is the audio duration - second parameter is the callback when the audio is finished
    self.isactive = true;
  });
  return this; // return this instance
};

myApp.prototype.play = function() { // play method
  var song = document.getElementById('audiosource');
  if (this.paused === true)
  {
    console.log('play song');
    song.play();
    this.paused = false;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('pause song');
    song.pause();
    this.paused = true;
  }
  return this;
};

myApp.prototype.countdown = function(duration, callback) { // countdown method
  var self = this, // class instance
       countdown = null, // countdown
       ctx = null; // setIntervall clearer
       timer = duration; // timer

  if (this.isactive === true) // if this method yet called
  {
    return false;
  }
  countdown = function() {
      console.log('start countdown:' + self.paused);
    if (timer === 0)
    {
       clearInterval(ctx);
       callback.call(this);
       return false;
    }
    if (self.paused === false) // if not in pause
    {
      timer -= 1;
      console.log(timer);
         self.timeleft = timer;

      $('#timer > span').html(timer);
    }
  };
  ctx = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
};

myApp.prototype.onEnd = function() {
  // when the audio is finish..
 alert ('end of the song');
};

;$(function() {
 new myApp();
});
```

Comment: I'd also suggest not to pass `duration` to `countdown` and remove `timer` in `countdown`. Also seems that you wanted `ctx = null,` in place of `ctx = null;`. http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/

Comment: @user2732367 Well, I think there is more work should be done on this code, but yes, you can go with this code. If you want user to be able to set timer to whatever value he wants, you can write setter function for `timer`, similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/1/).

Comment: @user2732367 I mean you should clean up some parts. For example you do `this.paused = false; this.paused = true` in `myApp`. First, you should stick with one of them, second you should use `;` at the end of second assignment. Also, as I already told, you are incidentally introducing global `timer` variable in `countdown`. But, since the code works correctly you surely can use it.

Comment: @zaquest Also i want to play the 5 sounds count saying(1,2,3,4,5) just after the first audio i.e `audiosource`  . Here is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/3/ , please help

Comment: Clearly i asked this question here ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069127/jquery-facing-issue-with-timer-and-audio-playback

Comment: @zaquest  This is my last question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069127/jquery-facing-issue-with-timer-and-audio-playback  . `Please help me with question, Actually i am just a beginner in scripting language`  .Actually i am a Back-end developer in Java.